# Cover text() node of existing node from new node - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing html to xml transformation. In html I have table like this,

```
<doc>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>List<span style="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</span></p>
        <ol>
            <li>nested list1</li>
            <li>nested <span style="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</span> list1</li>
            <li>nested list1</li>
            <li>nested list1</li>
            <li>nested list1</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>List<span style="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>List<span style="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</span></p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here I need to transform html elements names to certain xml elements name and should cover the text content by `<para>` element.

SO my output should be,

```
<doc>
    <oli>
        <listitem><para>List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style></para>
            <oli>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested <style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style> list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
            </oli>
        </listitem>
        <listitem><para>
            List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style>
        </para></listitem>
        <listitem><para>
            List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style>
        </para></listitem>
    </oli>
</doc>
```

I have written following xsl to transform html to xml,

```
<xsl:template match="ol">
        <oli>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>           
        </oli>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <listitem>
            <para>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </para>
        </listitem>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <style type="{@style}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </style>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li/p">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem I have is when `ul` contain nested list, `li` text that has contain nested list is not correctly covered with `<para>` element.

in above example currunt output that I'm getting  for nested list is follwos,

```
<listitem><para>
            List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style>
            <oli>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested <style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style> list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
                <listitem><para>nested list1</para></listitem>
            </oli>
        </para></listitem>
```

so simply, instead of

```
<listitem><para>
                List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style>
                <oli>
              ........
                </oli>
             </para>
 </listitem>
```

I need,

```
    <listitem><para>
           List<style type="color: rgb(255,0,255);">The scope of this project is to:</style>
           </para>
                    <oli>
                  ........
                    </oli>

     </listitem>
```

I tried to cover `text()` content of `li` element by `<para>` but then `<span>` elements are not coming to the output.

Can anyone suggest a method how can I do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply change the template:

```
<xsl:template match="li/p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="li[p]">
   <listitem>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </listitem>
</xsl:template>
```

This template will match an `<li>` that contains a `<p>`. In this case, you don't have to add some `<para>`. For the `<li>`s that contain some `<p>`, the other template will match, and it does output the desired `<para>`.

*Alternatively*, you can also do something like this:

- discard the template `<xsl:template match="li/p">`
- modify the template `<xsl:template match="li">` like follows:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="p">
        <listitem>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </listitem>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <listitem>
          <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </para>
        </listitem>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  ```